# ShowDialog in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

When I make two calls for ShowDialog in WPF the first window open normally, **after closing it** the second one doesn't appear.

```
<Application 
    x:Class="Test.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Startup="App_OnStartup">
</Application>

private void App_OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    var windowA = new WindowA();
    windowA.ShowDialog();

    var windowB = new WindowB();
    windowB.ShowDialog();
}
```

WindowA:

```
<Window x:Class="Test.WindowA"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="WindowA" Height="129.452" Width="313.356">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Margin="139,54,0,0"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>

public partial class WindowA : Window
{
    public WindowA()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

WindowB:

```
<Window x:Class="Test.WindowB"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="WindowB" Height="221.918" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <RadioButton Content="RadioButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="124,63,0,0"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>

public partial class WindowB : Window
{
    public WindowB()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: The second one doesn't appear when? Even after WindowA is closed? Only one modal/dialog can be displayed at a time.

Comment: The second one doesn't appear after closing the first one.

Comment: ok done, you can check it again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In WPF you can specify when application shuts down and by default [`Application.ShutdownMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.shutdownmode.aspx) is `OnLastWindowClose` which means that when last `Window` is closed applications shuts down and  in your case first `Window` is also last. When you open and close first `Window` your application shuts down and that's why you don't see second `Window`. You would need to change `ShutdownMode` to `OnExplicitShutdown`

```
<Application ... ShutdownMode="OnExplicitShutdown"/>
```

but this means that even when you close all your windows application is still running so you have to explicitly call [`Application.Shutdown()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.shutdown.aspx) to shutdown your application, for example when main window is closed.

Comment: May you explain more?

Comment: @MSA which part needs clarification?

Comment: Is this a part of the application life-cycle, and where to know about those modes?

Comment: @MSA updated my answer with a bit more explanation. Hope it helps

Comment: @MSA there is a link in my answer that explains how `ShutdownMode` works [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shutdownmode.aspx) is a link `ShutdownMode` type with all possible options

Answer (score 4):

ShowDialog() function invokes the window modally. Which means code after windowA.ShowDialog(); will not execute until that window is closed.

Comment: The second one doesn't appear after closing the first one.